# Flutter app only working with WiFi and not mobile data

Tags: android, flutter

I have a flutter app that is working fine with WiFi but when I switch to mobile data its not working. I have checked and I have internet connection because my other sites and apps are working.

On the Android side I have in my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then inside the application tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
       android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"/>
```

Then inside the network_security_config.xml file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.mydomain.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
 </network-security-config>
```

I am using a package nb_utils and under the hood it uses connectivity_plus to check for internet connection and to check for connectivity I have:

```
ConnectivityResult connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  print('I have Data access');
  return true;
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  print('I have WIFI access');
  return true;
}
print('I have NO access');
return false;
```

And I am getting 'I have Data access' printed in the console when I am connected to mobile data.

At first I was using http://shop.mydomain.com on my URI but then I had to apply an SSL certificate on my domain to see if its working but still got the same thing using https://shop.mydomain.com. I am not getting any error(s) in my console as well. I havent tried this on iOS as yet, I have only added:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

in the Info.plist.

Comment: I also have the same problem, has anyone managed to solve it?

Comment: Same to me. Have you figured out why is this happening?

Comment: Same problem here... Anyone has figure how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is stuck with this issue and lands here: My issue was that I was building in debug, if you build in release mode my issue was solved. or vice versa, I cant remember which one worked and the other did not between the 2 release modes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

When mobile data was on, I tried to access the endpoint using a browser and postman, but I was unable. Then I realized that the problem is not related to flutter or my code.

Before researching further, I recommend trying to send a request without using your flutter app when only mobile data is active.

> P.S. *mobile data = cellular data*

Comment: Yeah I remember trying that out. That did not solve my issue, even tried internet from different service providers but that did not work for me